# Is it possible to get template content in directive link function?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I want to reuse **directive template**. How could I get an access to it inside a **link function**?

I expect something like

```
this.template
```

Answer (score 2):

You must use template cache service.

```
$templateCache.get('path/to/template/my.html')
```

[http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$templateCache](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/%24templateCache)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this is possible, but you can make the template a function. For example you can have a templateUrl that is a function and returns different templates. eg

```
templateUrl: function(element,attr){
   if (attr.type == 'select'){
       return 'views/select.html
   } else {
       return 'views/standard.html
   }
},
```

Its a basic example, but gets the idea across. What do you need the template in the link function for?

Comment: but how could I get template in link function?